# Datagridview optimization VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rows

I just want to ask if there is another alternative for filling up the cells in the datagridview. Currently I'm using this code :

For i = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex To x - 1

```
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("LastName").Value = empcoll.Item(i).LastName
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("FirstName").Value = empcoll.Item(i).FirstName
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("MiddleName").Value = empcoll.Item(i).MiddleName
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("CreatedBy").Value = empcoll.Item(i).CreatedBy
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("CreateDate").Value = empcoll.Item(i).CreateDate
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Status").Value = empcoll.Item(i).Status
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("DailySalary").Value = empcoll.Item(i).DailySalary
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("BirthDate").Value = empcoll.Item(i).BirthDate



    Next i
```

but when I use it for databases with a large number of records, it tends to load slow and hangs up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQLDataSource control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) and then bind the DataGridView to the SQLDataSource.  It is described here: http://www.vkinfotek.com/gridview/bind-gridview-sqldatasource-control.html.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should be Data Binding the columns to the properties on the objects instead of the method you're currently using.

It would look something like this

```
LastNameColumn.DataPropertyname = "LastName"
FirstNameColumn.DataPropertyname = "FirstName"
....
DataGridView1.DataSource = MyListofEmployeeObjects
```

As far as the load speed, there are two options: pagination, and virtual mode.

With pagination, you can pull X of Y records from the database at a time and display them in the grid.

Virtual mode ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx ) enables the DataGridView to handle automatic pulling/pushing of the records from/to the database so that you do not have to load all records at once.

Comment: I'm storing the data from the database into a List (of T) in this case a list of employee. 

I have no idea for pagination do you have some resources for that?
Also I'm looking at virtual mode right now (with the link you've suggested)

Comment: For pagination it really depends on how you're getting them from the database, and which database you're using. The basic idea is that you pick how many items you'll show per page, then get that many items. It involves skipping to the first item that would be on the page, and then selecting only as many items as you would like to display on that page.

Comment: I realized that I wouldn't be doing pagination at the moment.

I'm using virtualmode now but all my cells are being filled with the same entry. 

 e.Value = empcoll.Item(0).FirstName <<on the cellvalueneeded event

how will I add the values to each column using virtual mode?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I prefer to use the  DatagridView.Rows.Add method for unbounded DataGridViews.

Something like this:

```
Dim loData(7) as object
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
For i = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex To x - 1
   loData(0) = empcoll.Item(i).LastName
   loData(1) = empcoll.Item(i).FirstName
   loData(2) = empcoll.Item(i).MiddleName
   loData(3) = empcoll.Item(i).CreatedBy
   loData(4) = empcoll.Item(i).CreateDate
   loData(5) = empcoll.Item(i).Status
   loData(6) = empcoll.Item(i).DailySalary
   loData(7) = empcoll.Item(i).BirthDate
   DataGridView1.Rows.Add(loData)
Next i
```

I usually declare en enum to give a meaning name to each array element and make the code cleaner:

```
private enum eCols
   LastName
   Firstname
   MiddleName
   CreatedBy
   CreateDate
   Status
   DailySalary
   BirthDate
end enum

Dim loData(7) as object
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
For i = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex To x - 1
   loData(eCol.LastName) = empcoll.Item(i).LastName
   loData(eCol.FirstName) = empcoll.Item(i).FirstName
   loData(eCol.MiddleName) = empcoll.Item(i).MiddleName
   loData(eCol.CreatedBy) = empcoll.Item(i).CreatedBy
   loData(eCol.CreateDate) = empcoll.Item(i).CreateDate
   loData(eCol.Status) = empcoll.Item(i).Status
   loData(eCol.DailySalary) = empcoll.Item(i).DailySalary
   loData(eCol.BirthDate) = empcoll.Item(i).BirthDate
   DataGridView1.Rows.Add(loData)
Next i
```